# Getting error's in swift 3 xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have converted old Swift code to the new Swift3 in Xcode. Now it is showing these errors in my Swift file:

```
self.detailViewController = controllers[controllers.count- 1].topViewController as? DetailViewController
```

**Error**:

> value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'topViewController'

```
let sortedTimes = sorted(times!){a,b in a.0.rawValue < b.0.rawValue}
```

**Error**:

> 'sorted' is unavailable: call the sort() method on the collection

Comment: try this  self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one could be that your `UINavigationController` is put in a collection of `UIViewController`s. You need to let the compiler know that it is really a `UINavigationController`.

```
self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count - 1] as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? DetailViewController
```

The second one is that the `sorted` function has now become an instance method.

```
let sortedTimes = times!.sorted { $0.0.rawValue < $1.0.rawValue }
```

Comment: the second one the fix takes the error away but then the next lines gives me an error any idea

 todayTimes = sortedTimes
            tableView.reloadData(sorted)

Comment: What is the error that you get on the next lines @sabrefm1?

Answer (score 0):

Swift has the `type safety` feature which is done at compile time. `controllers[controllers.count - 1` must be of type `UINavigationController`. So you have to cast it accordingly.

```
self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count - 1] as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? DetailViewController
```

Suppose collection (array) contains int values.

```
let times : NSArray = [1,2,3,4]
let sortedTimes = times.sorted(by: {a,b in (a as! Int) < (b as! Int)})
```

You can update the `as!` downcast to your specified type ( `{a,b in (a as AnyObject).rawValue < b.0.rawValue}` ).

Comment: Technically it's not wrong to say Swift 3 is type-safe. However, AFAIK, Swift has always been type-safe.

Comment: the first answer is correct but I still seem to be getting an error on the second
call the sort() method

Answer (score 0):

use this line,

```
let sortedTimes = times.sort({a,b in a.0.rawValue < b.0.rawValue})
```

Hope this will help you.